# Remove languages from spell checker

Tags: rich-text, spellchecker

What is the best way to hide or remove languages from the spell checker? I want to reduce the available languages down to only three entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to do this in javascript. The languages are not actually removed and the script must be run every time a page loads in edit mode, but the result is that any language(s) can be hidden from the spell-checker list.

The languages available to the spell checker is exposed in a global javascript object

```
window.spellcheck; //The spellcheck object
spellcheck.defaultLanguage; //The lcid for the default language
spellcheck.languages; //An array of all available languages with name and lcid
spellcheck.siteUrl; //The url to the current SPSite (I think)
```

To remove languages you don't want to display simply remove them from the *languages* array.

This is a short version of the code I'm using (requires jQuery):

```
var keepLanguagesLCID = [1044, 2068, 1033]; //Keep bokmål, nynorsk and english.
//Filter the languages array and extract only those languages with a valid lcid.
spellcheck.languages = $.grep(spellcheck.languages, function (elem, idx) {
    return $.inArray(elem.lcid, keepLanguagesLCID) >= 0;
});
```